# How do i download a file with the new HttpClient?

Tags: angular, file, get, blob, httpclient

So how it used to work is that i did a 'GET' and provided an ID and with the returned data i just had to do this:

```
const subscription = this.downloadService.downloadFile(id, this.file.folderId).subscribe(data => {
    window.location.href = data.url;
    subscription.unsubscribe();
});
```

And Chrome would automatically download the file and stay on the site.

Now i do this:

```
const subscription = this.downloadFile(id, folderId).subscribe(data => {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'image' });
    const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.location.href = blobUrl;
    subscription.unsubscribe();  
});
```

And Chrome also starts a download but it's always the same file, looking like this in console:

[image]

I tried converting it to a file, but the 'window.location.href' needs a URL and i don't have that when i convert it to a file like this:

```
const file = new File([blob], name, { lastModified: Date.now(), type: 'image' })
```

What do I need to do with this data to make sure it download it as an image (it's always images that I try to download)?

EDIT: So apparently my httpParams were implemented wrong! This was the wrong way:

```
const httpParams = new HttpParams();
httpParams.append('action', 'downloadFile');
httpParams.append('fileIds', id.toString());
httpParams.append('currentLibraryFolderId', folderId.toString());
```

Which passed just an empty httpParams. This is the correct way:

```
const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('action', 'downloadFile')
    .set('fileIds', id.toString())
    .set('currentLibraryFolderId', folderId.toString());
```

Comment: You're specifying the mime type of `text/csv` when you instantiate your blob, make sure to set it to the correct type

Comment: if I use 'image' or 'image/png' (for png's) i get the same result. it still returns a BLOB. The wierd thing is that it's always the same size: 266. Regardless which file i try to download. I edited the question, it should indeed be mime type 'image'

Comment: 'Blob' is correct, that's not an issue, it's just a class used to represent binary data. If you check in the browsers developer tools (in the network tab), does the response data coming back from your server look correct?

Comment: Good question, havent checked yet. When i check i get a 200 status but the response says: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in download.php on line 147. I can run this by the back end developer here, maybe they know whats up.

Comment: I have a feeling the problem lies with my httpParams. Gonna look into that!

Comment: The problem was in my httpParams that were wrong. Thanks for helping me though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `window.open(url)`:

> If type will be browser supported like `image` or `pdf` etc. it will
>   open otherwise download it.

HTML:

```
<a (click)="downloadFile(fileData, type)" download>Download File</a>
```

For Download and save Using `FileSaver`:

```
 npm install file-saver --save

 import { saveAs } from 'file-saver/FileSaver';
```

If you are getting response as `arraybuffer`

```
var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type});

var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

saveAs(blob, filename);

var winOpen = window.open(url);


// If Popup blocked
if (!winOpen || winOpen.closed || typeof winOpen.closed == 'undefined') {
       alert( 'Please disable your Pop-up blocker and try again.');
 }
```

Comment: In my case it want to open a new tab, but Chrome blocks this.

Comment: Thanks, this can serve as e temporary solution. But I want the user to have it download the image directly without an alert. Also that it doesnt open it but download it.

Comment: and also 'download' on element using that you bare downloading file.

Comment: Is it not possible to do it natively without an external package? I find it very wierd that this is so badly documented. Not diminishing your help though!

Comment: have u added download on element?

Comment: I haven't tried the package. I work in a project where external packages are more of a pain then a help. Ill mark your answer as correct because it actually is. But i need to do it without packages, just natively in browser